# Damped sinusoidal form FFT of signal

Tags: signals, signal-processing, fft, analysis

I'm doing an assignment for the course Signal analysis where I have to analyse a signal. I've tried quite some things now but it's still bothering me that the FFT is looking weird, and not looks like the 'normal look' FFT's we learned in class.

FFT (absolute values of complex values): 
[FFT abs values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHxC9.png) - [FFT abs values zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZWcy.png)

FFT (no absolute values): 
[FFT zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf5i8.png)

The FFT seen in the image above is zoomed in on the frequency range 0-30Hz. The rest of the frequency range does not show a lot of (high) peaks, which probably are caused by noise.

The signal is created during a method of welding, using an oscilloscope with a sampling frequency of 1000Hz. I've filtered the signal to remove noise, and after that the signal is converted to the frequency spectrum using the fft function of MATLAB.

Signal before and after filtering:
[Original signal and filtered signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwb7Q.png)

My general question is, can the shown FFT be valid or did I make a mistake? I estimated the ground frequency to be around 5.5Hz, can I say this when I take one period of the big sinusoidal wave? I also noticed there are about 64 little sinusoidal waves inside one (ground??) period, is this an high harmonic wave form?.

If my theory is right, what causes the fft to be a damped sinusoidal form?

The code I use is basically the following. I leave the part of the noise filtering out because I don't think it's necessary for this question. The dataset is an matrix of 40100 rows.

```
fs = 1000;
cleanSignaal = data(:,4);
fftSignal = fft(cleanSignaal)/lenght(cleanSignaal);
f = fs/(2*length(fftSignal)):fs/length(fftSignal):fs;
plot(f,abs(fftSignal));
xlim([0 fs(m)/2]);
title('Fast Fourier Transform')
xlabel('Frequentie (Hz)')
ylabel('Magnitude')
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is the magnitude negative?  Are you sure you a plotting the FFT and not time domain plot?

Comment: I've not taken the absolute values of the FFT. When I take the absolute values the FFT is a mess even more, as can be seen in: https://imgur.com/a/zkkxdp7

Comment: When zooming in you can kind of see the same pattern (https://imgur.com/a/pYK3ENK), but it's quite hard te analyse. Can you tell me why the highest amplitudes are around 0Hz? I thought I learned the 0Hz frequency doesn't really exists and therefore can be neglected.

Comment: Could you please show a plot of the data that is used to get this FFT?  (You might need to zoom in a bit so we can set the relevant timescale.)  Also, have you tried to take the inverse of the FFT, to check whether you get the original signal back?

Comment: This is the data before and after the Wiener Filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwb7Q.png I havent used the ifft function yet.

Comment: I checked and the ifft is a 100% copy of the original signal. I've also added some info above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks correct: your signal is a pulse with some noise on it, and the FFT is basically a [`sinc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function (or `abs` of a sinc as you should plot it for an FFT) which is what you'd expect for a pulse.

Here's a simple demo of this.  (Btw, I made the pulse a bit narrower than yours with the goal of making the `sinc` wider, which works since the widths are inversely related.  This way I don't have to zoom in.)

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For ploting

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 1., N)
y = ( (t>0.46) & (t<0.54)).astype(float)

f = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y))
faxis = np.fft.rfftfreq(y.size, 1./N)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.ylim(-.1, 1.1)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(faxis, f)
plt.ylim(0, 90)
plt.show()
```

On top of the pulse you have a lot of spikey noise, which are added to the FFT.  This will generally have spectral qualities mostly far away from the low frequencies of the sinc, but this can depend on the exact nature of the noise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It indeed seems to clarify what's happening. Is there any information which can be subtracted from the fft in my case? What is the meaning of those wave periods of the sinc function in the fft spectrum?

Comment: There's probably not anything that you can see in the FFT of the pulse that isn't easier to get from the pulse itself.  The widths of the sinc and pulse are inversely related, so you could determine the pulse width (which is probably easier to do in the time domain) and the total power in each will be the same (by Parseval's theorem -- but again easier in time domain).  Also, I suppose you could fit to the sinc and remove it and be left with the transform of only the noise (although probably easier to do in the time domain as well).

Comment: @Jost: Also, I reread you question and I don't see what you mean by a "ground period". I don't see any sign of something periodic either directly in the time domain or a time-domain periodicity represented in the FFT. (Although, of course, the FFT assumes the time domain signal is periodic with the sample length.)

Comment: In the assignment they ask for the basic period and the bandwidth/accuracy in relation with the time of measurement. In addition to the signal plotted above, I also have measurements of a signal of the voltage (https://imgur.com/a/9llqRJD). They show some periodicity, so I'll compute the period from there. Btw, what do you exactly mean by fitting the sinc and remove it and be left with the transform of the noise only?

Comment: I think I've answered your basic question, and there are a lot of things in this assignment that you know but I don't (eg, what you've covered in class, the actual data, etc), so I can't really work through the whole thing with you, and I'll basically leave this here. By "fitting the sync" I mean: since you know it's a pulse and the pulse FFTs into a sinc, you can do a numerical fit to the sinc form in the FFT as way of removing it from the FFT (in complex space, not on the abs). I'm not recommending this for your problem, just saying it could be done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it! Ok, I'll see if it can help me somewhere.